# RenderFlex Overflow by Infinity Pixels on the Bottom error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

```
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFlex#8f8d6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=160.0, h=230.0)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: start
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
The constraints that applied to the RenderPointerListener were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=160.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(160.0, Infinity)
```

[image: Error image in the emulator]

[image: Layout Explorer Image]

I am using this

```
Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://www.seriouseats.com/thmb/TIHHSzYffxJilgk77uGlPV_AD6g=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/chocolate-oreo-cake-recipe-HERO-a6080fae715b4453b54800c69029e230.jpg'),
),
```

It shows 'RenderFlex overlfowed by Inifinity Pixels on the Bottom' error

Comment: what is the parent widget, also it will be easier if you could include sample widget from scaffold body

Comment: wrap your root container with SingleChildScrollView.